# UITableViewCell background image

Tags: objective-c

I have a small problem with the UITableviewCell. i'm using the code:

```
UIView *cellBackView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        cellBackView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"Navigation.png"]];
        cell.backgroundView = cellBackView;
```

But look what happend ; 
http://cl.ly/070f1C3n143v0W1Y2g2Q

Somebody know how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because of the labels that are in the way (in front of the background)
add this and it should be fixed

```
cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```